# Need advice in seq2seq model implementation

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, seq2seq

I am implementing seq2seq model for text summerization using tensorflow. For encoder I'm using a bidirectional RNN layer. encoding layer:

```
    def encoding_layer(self, rnn_inputs, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, 
                   source_vocab_size, 
                   encoding_embedding_size,
                   source_sequence_length,
                   emb_matrix):

    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_matrix, rnn_inputs)

    stacked_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(rnn_size), keep_prob) for _ in range(num_layers)])

    outputs, state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=stacked_cells, 
                                                             cell_bw=stacked_cells, 
                                                             inputs=embed, 
                                                             sequence_length=source_sequence_length, 
                                                             dtype=tf.float32)

    concat_outputs = tf.concat(outputs, 2)

    return concat_outputs, state[0]
```

For decoder I'm using attention mechanism. Decoding Layer:

```
    def decoding_layer_train(self, encoder_outputs, encoder_state, dec_cell, dec_embed_input, 
                         target_sequence_length, max_summary_length, 
                         output_layer, keep_prob, rnn_size, batch_size):
    """
    Create a training process in decoding layer 
    :return: BasicDecoderOutput containing training logits and sample_id
    """

    dec_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(dec_cell, 
                                             output_keep_prob=keep_prob)


    train_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(dec_embed_input, target_sequence_length)

    attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention(rnn_size, encoder_outputs,
                                                               memory_sequence_length=target_sequence_length)

    attention_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(dec_cell, attention_mechanism,
                                                         attention_layer_size=rnn_size/2)

    state = attention_cell.zero_state(dtype=tf.float32, batch_size=batch_size)
    state = state.clone(cell_state=encoder_state)

    decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=attention_cell, helper=train_helper, 
                                              initial_state=state,
                                              output_layer=output_layer) 
    outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder, impute_finished=True, maximum_iterations=max_summary_length)

    return outputs
```

Now, initial state of BasicDecoder function expects state of shape = (batch_size, rnn_size). My encoder outputs two states(forward & backward) of shape= (batch_size, rnn_size).

To make it work I'm using only one state of encoder(forward state). So, I want to know the possible ways to use both backward encoding and forward encoding of encoding layer. Should I add both forward and backward states?

P.S. - decoder don't use bidirectional layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only the backward encoding:

```
# Get only the last cell state of the backward cell
(_, _), (_, cell_state_bw) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(...)
# Pass the cell_state_bw as the initial state of the decoder cell
decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(..., initial_state=cell_state_bw, ...)
```

What I suggest you do:

```
# Get both last states
(_, _), (cell_state_fw, cell_state_bw) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(...)
# Concatenate the cell states together
cell_state_final = tf.concat([cell_state_fw.c, cell_state_bw.c], 1)
# Concatenate the hidden states together
hidden_state_final = tf.concat([cell_state_fw.h, cell_state_bw.h], 1)
# Create the actual final state
encoder_final_state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(c=cell_state_final, h=hidden_state_final)
# Now you can pass this as the initial state of the decoder
```

However, beware, the size of the decoder cell has to be twice the size of the encoder cell for the second approach to work.

Comment: After tf.concat() on forward and backward states. The shape of final result is (2, 4, ?, 128). Which is a mismatch to the shape which decoder expects. So, it results in an error.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, I get that. But, why I'm getting this weird shape after concat?

Comment: I apologize. My answer was not complete. Now it should be fine.

Comment: Right now I'm using two layered LSTM cell for encoder. I tried what you have recommended for single layer encoder. But, still I'm having issues. I have spent my day solving this, but, still I don't know what's going wrong. Here's the full code: https://github.com/sainimohit23/Text-Summarization . Please help. I want to learn this.

Comment: Also, if I use say 2 layered LSTM for encoder. Then will I get a pair of forward and backward states  for each layer? or will I get only a single pair of cell states, no matter how many layers I use?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things already covered in previous responses.

Regarding your concern "Should I add both forward and backward states?", according to me we should use both the states of encoder. Otherwise we are not utilizing the trained backward encoder state.
Moreover "bidirectional_dynamic_rnn", should have two different layers of LSTM cells:
One for FW state and another one for BW state.